# What are the most notable and game changing features of the new Constantinople Ethereum upgrade?

Tags: upgrading, constantinople

The Constantinople Ethereum upgrade is a big upgrade to the network. What are some of the most notable and game changing features of this new upgrade?

Answer (score -3):

There is a great article on this by mycrypto [here](https://medium.com/mycrypto/ethereum-constantinople-everything-you-need-to-know-a47f3a16f3d2)

some of the notable points

[- EIP 1014: Skinny CREATE2](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014)

-[EIP 1234: Constantinople Difficulty Bomb Delay and Block Reward Adjustment](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1234)

Comment: Hi there. Link-only answers are discouraged as the link could be moved or die, rendering your answer useless. Can you summarise the contents of the link in a proper answer?